# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Routing error on '/sessions'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing Michael Hartls Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I am getting a routing error when I try to browse to localhost:3000/sessions

Routing Error

No route matches "/sessions"

From the tutorial, I was under the impression that rails will infer the route to "sessions" and I would not need to add a specification route to routes.rb.

If I run rake routes I get the following

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
            POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"} 
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
   root        /(.:format)               {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
 signup        /signup(.:format)         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
 signin        /signin(.:format)         {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
signout        /signout(.:format)        {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
  about        /about(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
contact        /contact(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
   help        /help(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
```

My routes.rb contains

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root              :to => 'pages#home'

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
```

I can get it to work if I add the following line to routes.rb, but I didn't think I needed to do this explicitly

```
  match '/sessions',:to => 'sessions#create'
```

Am I missing something or misunderstanding something?
I am running Rails 3.0.11 and Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In rails a `GET` verb request to `/sessions` routes to the `index` action.

You either need to browse to `/sessions/new`, or add the additional match like you've done in the last part of your question.

These are the default routes for a `resource`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions